# How to join with a group by and where, including 0 values

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I've got some sort of static table like:

SELECT * FROM targets;

```
name   | target
name1  |      6
name2  |      3
name3  |      2
```

and another table with the actual records inside, that I want to measure:

SELECT * FROM records;

```
id   | name  | created_on   
546  | name1 | 2022-06-02  
547  | name2 | 2022-06-04  
548  | name2 | 2022-06-07
```

Now I'd like to build a table, that groups / counts the records per name (per month).
The group by is easy (except the 0 values):

```
SELECT "name", COUNT("id") FROM "records"
WHERE MONTH("created_on") = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
AND YEAR("created_on") = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
GROUP BY "name"
```

But how do I join both tables to get a result like this?

```
name   | target | current
name1  |      6 |       1
name2  |      3 |       2
name3  |      3 |       0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your data

```
CREATE TABLE targets(
   name   VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL 
  ,target INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO targets
(name,target) VALUES 
('name1',6),
('name2',3),
('name3',2);

CREATE TABLE records(
   id         INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,name       VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL
  ,created_on DATE  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO records
(id,name,created_on) VALUES 
(546,'name1','2022-06-02'),
(547,'name2','2022-06-04'),
(548,'name2','2022-06-07');
```

you should use  `Join`(Left or Right) to include all values including null values and `IF` logical operator and `Subquery` to act as table for your query

```
SELECT targets.name,
       target,
       IF(current IS NULL, 0, current) AS current
FROM   targets 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT name,
                         Count(id) current
                  FROM   records
                  WHERE  Month(created_on) = Month(CURRENT_DATE())
                         AND Year(created_on) = Year(CURRENT_DATE())
                  GROUP  BY name) records
              ON records.name = targets.name
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=707d8d8cda00d31ef130ace7e3990696)